# SFSafariViewController Title

Tags: ios, objective-c, mobile-safari

I have SFSafariViewController working fine in Objective-C, but have not been able to set a separate title (other than the default URL). Does anyone know how to set a separate title?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't set the title for SFSafariViewController.

It's a controller provided for showing the default view of your web page.

If you want to set the title on your web view then you can use WKWebView inside your own controller and can provide all the customisation there.