# How to change SFSafariviewController's Title in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, sfsafariviewcontroller

I am Opening web page in Application using **`SFSafariViewController.`**

I used below code to open SafariViewController:

```
  let url = URL.init(string: myURL)
  let safari = SFSafariViewController(url: url!)
  self.presentVC(vc: safari)
```

It is working fine. But How can I change it's Title?
[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3iAP.png)

I have tried below code:

```
 safari.title = "About Us"
```

But No Success.

Also search for same but didn't get any answer [SFSafariViewController Title](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31914675).

Comment: there is no option for change the title

Answer (score 11):

As the introduction of the documentation suggests, `SFSafariViewController` is for securely displaying web content in an app. The user can trust that he doesn't see manipulated web content. If you could change the title, you could foist pages from a wrong domain to the user and that would open the door for phishing attacks.

For this reason, Apple will not have provided any possibility to change the title.